# Is there any API to provision the Office 365 Group Site?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

When we click the File/Site in OWA, it will redirect to a SharePoint page like this: https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/groupstatus.aspx?id=&target=documents

In this page, the office 365 group site will be created if the Group site is not existing.

Like user OneDrive site, we can provision it via Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.GetDefaultDocumentLibrary 
So is there any API provisioning group site for specified group? Microsoft Graph API, AAD Graph or SharePoint Client API, any one?

And when I create an Office 365 Group in Office 365 Portal, the group site will be created automatically after some minutes. But when I create the group in exchange online or by MS Graph API, the group site cannot be created. When I try to access /groups/groupid/drive, I got this error

> Status Code: 404
>
> {
>      "error": {
>          "code": "ResourceNotFound",
>          "message": "Resource provisioning is in progress. Please try again.",
>          "innerError": {
>              "request-id": "4f7e6581-4092-4fdb-834f-67c0b4f400b4",
>              "date": "2016-11-22T05:59:52"
>          }
>      }
>   }

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pre-created the Files (SharePoint site) after Office 365 Group provisioning, all by using PowerShell

1. New-UnifiedGroup / creates Office 365 group
2. Grab the Group ID using Get-UnifiedGroup, property "ExternalDirectoryObjectId"
3. Connect-PnPMicrosoftGraph
4. Get-PnPUnifiedGroup with the ID

Comment: Exchange Online PowerShell is not a better solution for enterprise service. It has too many limitation, and is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

When creating groups through Microsoft Graph the expectation is that the SharePoint site is immediately available. Unfortunately the way the Microsoft Graph API is designed it allows creation of a group in app-only *without* providing an owner. That scenario is a broken scenario in SharePoint, because it translates into anonymously create a site and that’s unsupported.

In conclusion, if you are calling Microsoft Graph in app-only mode to create groups, pass the owner at creation time, not as subsequent operation post group creation.

In the JSON payload on creation you need to pass this in

```
"owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
]
```

This is explained here in the documentation https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_owners

Comment: Hi Jeremy, nice to meet you again. This is Adam(worked with you about GA 7 years ago). Nice change. I will try it. Right now, we use EWS to create Office 365 group as HttpRequest in Outlook. Will MS publish the EWS API about Office 365 Group. Thanks.

Comment: And EWS can impersonate any user to support multiple domain based on exchange email address policy when creating office 365 group. But MicrosoftGraph app-only token cannot do that. Is there any solution?

Comment: Why do you need to be able to impersonate any user? Isn't it enough to create the group with the app-only token and then set the owner and members?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to create group. But the allowExternalSenders and autoSubscribeNewMembers are not supported with app-only token. And alos, based on this article: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Choose-the-domain-to-use-when-creating-Office-365-Groups-7cf5655d-e523-4bc3-a93b-3ccebf44a01a, that doesn't support app-only token.

Comment: For example, I have two domains(d1 and d2) in my tenant, d1 is default. And I want to create an Office 365 Group with d2 domain. The MS graph API can support it with delegated permission token based on exchange email address policy. But how about app-only token?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a unified group using the Microsoft Graph API, it takes care of doing all the orchestration of provisioning all the services for the group, the mailbox for conversations, the calendar, the site with the document library for files, etc. Documentation here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups. You will need to specify "groupTypes": ["Unified"] in the body

Comment: I know this API to create O365 Group. The group site is not created immediately. I must go to OWA, click File/Site, the SharePoint page groupstatus.aspx will provision it.

Comment: @Yina - MSFT: I have to agree with Adam as site is not being created automatically and only if requested. Could you please elaborate on how we could achieve this?